# C# Многомерный ассоциативный массив или перегрузка свойств

Tags: c#

Те кто изучал java script или php, а потом переходили на C# наверное меня поймут. Как они бедные обходятся без многомерных ассоциативных массивов без строгой типизации и приведения типов? В общем ситуация такая - есть возможность написать кусок программы, ограничение в 10000 символов, ничего своего подгружать нельзя никакие Hashtable OR Dictionary. Вся прелесть работы с многомерными ассоциативными массивами -  в том что можно быстро - максимально быстро обратиться к его элементу по ключу - будь то числу или строке. в PHP таким примером может служить

['животные домашние'=>['кошка','собака','хомячок'],0=>['домашние','дикие'],'свойства'=>['пушистость'],25=>[1985, 1990,1995]]

Читал форумы C# - там говорят - зачем вам ассоциативные массивы? - используйте классы, это конечно прекрасно, но как обращаться к свойствам этих классов на других языках(здесь имеется ввиду алфавит разных языков мира и поддерживает ли C# UTF-8 - например создать свойство класса на русском?) или по цифре? и как мне добавить свойство в уже имеющийся объект на C#, удалить из объекта свойство или может быть назначить свойству объекта значение отличное от типа, указанного в свойстве этого объекта?

На php я бы сделал это просто:

```
class a
{
    protected $params = [];
    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->params['$name'] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name){
        return $this->params['$name'];
    }
}

$a_obj = new a();

$a_obj->some_param = [1987,'name'=>'Hero'];

echo $a_obj->some_param[0];
echo $a_obj->some_param['name'];
```

выведет 1987Hero

в общем - уважаемые программисты на C# помогите перейти к пониманию - как вы работаете с данными - типы которых вам не известны и количество тоже - возможно вы пишите какие то свои костыли на подобии перегрузки методов - смотрите к какому типу данных относятся входящие данные, заносите в LIST с указанным типом данных -  и опять же как положить в лист LIST данные с определенным индексом, например [25=>'mehanic', 58=>'auto'] - там обычно кладутся как попало - стек [0=>'mehanic',1=>'auto'] В общем для тех кто не понял - скажите я поясню свой вопрос.

P.S. вот эта тема для понимания сильно тормозит понимание всего языка в целом, из за этого он кажется каким то ущербным в использовании. Спасибо за понимание и за то что дочитали

Добавил 25.03.2019
наткнулся на рекомендации от Microsoft

```
var contacts = new[]
{
    new {
        Name = " Eugene Zabokritski",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0108", "425-555-0001" }
    },
    new {
        Name = " Hanying Feng",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "650-555-0199" }
    }
};
```

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays)

Comment: В С# для языка есть понятие `Culture`, значения надо хранить в ресурсах, при правильно сконфигурированных ресурсах компилятор сам создаст длл согласно описанным языкам. При этом класс должен быть один, выбор языка определяется 'Культурой'. Руками делать не надо, есть инструменты, например https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilJollans.Multi-LanguageforVisualStudio

Comment: Мы, бедные, используем Hashtable и Dictionary. А также dynamic. Нельзя подгружать уже готовые реализации? А на PHP вы ассоциативные массивы сами с нуля написали или таки используете готовые? Лады, скопируйте код [отсюда](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: C# поддерживает юникод. То есть вы можете использовать хоть русские буквы, хоть китайские иероглифы для имен классов, свойств, переменных.

Comment: нашел кое что по теме [ссылка](https://blog.foolsoft.ru/c-associativnyj-massiv-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многомерные ассоциативные массивы реализуются путем применения следующей конструкции

```
var contacts = new[]
{
    new {
        Name = " Eugene Zabokritski",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0108", "425-555-0001" }
    },
    new {
        Name = " Hanying Feng",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "650-555-0199" }
    }
};
```

[Источник MIcrosoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays)

Также тем, кто впервые столкнулся со строго типизированным языком программирования в помощь будет [эта статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables). Здесь вы найдете аналогию с JS и [как пример использования callback функций](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

Comment: Это не тот функционал, который вы запрашивали в своем вопросе. Здесь нельзя обращаться к элементу массива по ключу любого типа, только по целочисленному. Так что это не ответ на ваш вопрос. Да и сами элементы все будут строго содержать одно и то же.

Comment: например обратиться по ключу можно contacts[1].PhoneNumbers[0] - вопрос конечно остался - можно ли сделать обращение вида contacts[1]["PhoneNumbers"][0]... Я конечно и дальше предполагаю копать в этом вопросе, пока не приду к пониманию как программисты С# извращаются или легко обходят это

Answer (score -1):

В С# для национального языка есть понятие `Culture` [System.Globalization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Посмотреть текущуй язык можно выполнив:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString());
```

изменить культуру:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

Интернационализация: обеспечение возможности использования приложения без языковых или культурных барьеров. Информация о языке и культуре поступает из ресурса, а не жестко закодирована в приложении.
Локализация: перевод и включение продукта для определенной локали. На основе файла ресурсов приложение переводится на язык и культуру.

Подробнее тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/

Есть много сторонних инструментов для локализации, например https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilJollans.Multi-LanguageforVisualStudio

Попробуйте этот или другой инструмент на ваш выбор, не начинайте с 'ручных' правок.